# Azure service bus least privilege configuration

Tags: nservicebus, azureservicebus

We have multiple applications sharing a service bus namespace, however each application should only have read/write access to a subset of the queues in the namespace (let's say there's 40 queues and 2 apps, and each app should have read/write access to 20 queues each).

As far as I can see ASB allows placing a "Shared Access Key" on either the namespace level (where it will apply to all queues in the namespace), or on the queue level, where it will only apply to a single queue.

Since we're using ASB for cross-microservice communication we'll also have to deal with app A sending messages to app B etc. Which is one reason we're reluctant to provide each app with a unique namespace (the permissions matrix would get super-complicated)

We're struggling to figure out how to configure granular permissions without configuring unique namespaces per application (which would cause our costs to skyrocket). Did we miss something?

Comment: You can create shared access policy at the queue level so what is the problem ???

Comment: the problem is that a single app has to communicate with multiple queues. We'd like the app to (ideally) have a single credential to access ASB, which breaks if we use per-queue access policies.

Answer (score 1):

> We're struggling to figure out how to configure granular permissions without configuring unique namespaces per application (which would cause our costs to skyrocket). Did we miss something?

You did. Namespaces **do not cost money**. Operations, connections, and stored messages do. If you have a namespace with one namespace or ten, you'll still pay the same monthly fee for the Azure Service Bus service on the Standard or Premium tier.

Comment: Thanks for responding Sean. I've updated the question a bit.